# POST request to /API/login got 404 (not found)

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm implemnting sign in authentication using Google with this package (@react-OAuth /Google). I'm able to get the Google sign in button and its access token ID. I'm trying to send said token to the back end by making a POST request to '/api/login' endpoint. But it keeps telling me that 'http://localhost:3000/api/login' can not be found 404.

Welcome.js - where I make the POST request to back-end

```
<GoogleLogin
                        onSuccess={(credentialResponse) => {
                            //send the id token to server
                            fetch('/api/login', {
                                method: 'POST',
                                headers: {
                                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                },
                                body: JSON.stringify(credentialResponse.credential)
                            })
                                .then(res => res.json())
                                .then(data => {
                                    if(data.status === 'success') {
                                        //store the token id from credentialResponse into local storage to check if the user is logged in
                                        console.log(data.message)   
                                        navigate('/mymap', {replace:true})
                                    }else{
                                        console.error(data.message)
                                    }

                                })
                        }}
                        onError={() => {
                            console.log('Login Failed')
                            // display alert
                        }}
                    />
```

server.js

```
/****Imports****/
const express = require('express')

const port = 4000
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

/****Managing endpoints****/

//receiving google id token from front end...
app.post('/api/login', function (req,res){
    const {credential} = req.body
    
    console.log(credential)
    // decrypt the id token as base64-encoded JWT

    //verify the token

    //extract user info (name, picture, email, etc.) from id token to be store in MongoDB???
})


app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}...`)
})
```

All routes in my App.js

```
 <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<Welcome/>}/>
                <Route path='/mymap' element={<Map/>}/>
                <Route path='*' element={<Typography>Not found</Typography>}></Route>
</Routes>
```

I tried changing the endpoint from '/api/login' to the root '/', but it also gave me 'http://localhost:3000/' can not be found 404, which doesn't make sense because that my landing page and I'm able to see it

Comment: Notice the port in your url `:3000`. You are getting a 404 because you're trying to fetch your own UI route. This is because you are using a relative path in your fetch statement. Try using an explicit one like `http://localhost:4000/api/login` or better, some environment variable `fetch(\`${apiServerUrl}/api/login\`)`

Comment: @SterlingArcher thank you for your response! I tried both of your recommendations and the results are quite interesting... When I tried the env variable way, the endpoint got appended to localhost:3000/, like this 'http:/localhost:3000/4000/api/login'. When I did the explicit way, it told me 'Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy' and the error was ' POST http://localhost:4000/api/login net::ERR_FAILED'

Comment: Hey there! I'm glad you were able to get it figured out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sterling Archer, I found out the fetch() will usually append API endpoint to the localhost of my UI route by default.
The result is to do the explicit call like Sterling Archer suggested.
Also I have to install cors package for the front and the back end to communicate.